# Running the rest of the script with the function's string stuffs

Tags: python, function

I don't know how I can describe it on the title, but basically here is what I would like to describe in detail. This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
def test():
     text = 'Hello World'
     print(str(text))

test(),
print ("Function text is " + text)
```

which I would like the last line to print out `Function text is Hello World`, but it won't print out any way but showing `NameError: name 'text' is not defined`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should normally `return` from a function. This is captured in `b`.

```
def test():
     text = 'Hello World'
     return text

b = test()
print ("Function text is " + b)
```

Shorter one:

```
def test():
     return 'Hello World'
     
print ("Function text is " + test())
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `text` is visible only within the `test()` function. This means that if you refer to that variable outside of the `test()` function an error is shown. In addition, the variable `text` is already a string, so there is no need to write `str(text)`. If you want to print `Function text is Hello World` you have to do something like this:

```
def test():
     text = 'Hello World'
     return text

print("Function text is " + test())
```

The function `test()` returns the value of `text`. Then, the `print()` function prints `Function text is`  plus the value returned by `test()`, i.e., `Hello World`.